# <div>s are adding extra margin that I didn't specify

Tags: css, margin

Here is a demonstration of the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/jL69M/4/

I am trying to add a 3px margin to each block so that they separate apart from each other. Originally without the `margin: ...` all blocks will be stuck to each other, both horizontally and vertically, as expected. When I add in `margin-bottom: 3px`, the browser does add a 3px margin at the bottom, but it also seems to add another ~5px at the bottom. This is frustrating because I can't even select the spaces the browser generated.

So what exactly are those spaces? How can I get rid of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by the default `line-height`, which is set by the browser. By setting it to 0, every div will stack onto each other without extra spaces. Since the divs are set to be `inline-block`s, they will behave like inline elements such as `<img>`. Line height will apply to lines, which will affect all inline elements, which is the blocks in this case.

```css
#board{
    line-height: 0px;
}
```

This will solve the problem.